# Transparent block and picture inside the environment itemize

Tags: beamer, floats, overlays

Using Beamer I have one `figure` inside the environment `block` that is also inside the environment `itemize`. Using `begin{itemize}[<+->]` I have 3 items and the block with the figure is the 4th item. How do I keep the figure and block transparent until it is their time?.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. It would also be great if you could add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem rather than describing it.

Comment: The MWE can be just the frame that you have problem with. Then you can place it into a `\documentclass{beamer} ...\end{document}` and edit your question to include it.

Comment: With no MWE, this is too localized: request reopening when one is available.